# ACTION_WEB_SEARCH cannot be performed

Tags: android

In my application I do

```
    Uri webAddress = Uri.parse("http://www.nrk.no");
    Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH, webAddress);

    String title = "Choose an app";
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(webIntent, title);

    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

But the chooser that pops open says that `No apps can perform this action`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Changing to ACTION_VIEW made it work, why?

Comment: Where did you test this code? In emulator or real device?

Comment: Real device (galaxy s4 with 3 browsers installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH` but it looks like the difference is what action it actually takes. You aren't providing a [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/SearchManager.html#QUERY) to search for so the appropriate action would be `ACTION_VIEW`.

Take a look [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Browser). You could provide a query in the `Intent.EXTRAS` and see if that allows you to use `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`

Comment: I really don't have to use `ACTION_WEB_SEARCH`, I just thought that was correct for opening web browsers...

Comment: I understand. I was just trying to explain the difference of when and how to use the two.